# Exclude multiple subfolders while using Powershell's method Get-Childitem

Tags: powershell, foreach

#### What I have

The following working code lists all files from all subfolders where the script is placed.
It includes only certain file types and excludes all files from a certain single folder. So far so good

```
$fileInclude = @("*.txt", "*.hgr", "*.dat")           
$folderExclude = "C:\folder2"    
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

gci $scriptPath -recurse -include $fileFilter | Where {$_.FullName -notlike "$folderExclude*"}
```

The file structure for my test was as shown

```
C:.
│   Myscript.ps1
│
├───folder1
│   │   file1.dat
│   │   file1.hgr
│   │   file1.txt
│   │
│   └───folder3
│           file3.dat
│           file3.hgr
│           file3.txt
│
└───folder2
        file3.dat
        file3.hgr
        file3.txt
```

#### What I want

Now I want to replace the second line

```
$folderExclude = "C:\folder2"
```

with an array. Later there are dozens of paths in it.

```
$folderExclude = @(
        "C:\folder2", 
        "C:\folder1\folder3"    
        )
```

Obviously this won't work since `-notlike` expects a string and not an array of strings.

I can't get my head around how to implement this. I think I need a for-each loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also go this route:

```
$exclude = @('c:\folder2*', 'c:\folder1\folder3'} 
gci | Where {$fn = $_.Fullname; ($exclude | Where {$fn -like $_}).count -eq 0}
```

And if you are on V4, you can use the handy new common parameter -PipelineVariable:

```
gci -pv fse | Where {($exclude | Where {$fse.FullName -like $_}).count -eq 0}
```

Note that this approach has a flaw where if folder1 contains a file called folder3foobar, that file will get excluded.  To fix that, you would need to modify the exclude terms to c:\folder1\folder3* and then when you compare against the fse.FullName, you would need to append a backslash if fse was a directory instead of a file.

Here's another approach that works based on `-match` allowing arrays on the left hand side:

```
 gci | Where {!($exclude -match [regex]::escape($_.Fullname))}
```

In this case, if one of the directories does match the $exclude array of terms, then there will be output and that is coerced to true but then gets inverted by the `!`.

Comment: I don't understand how your first example exactly works. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: The command Where (or Where-Object) is merely expected to return a value that can be interpreted as true or false.  Inside that predicate scriptblock (inside the {}), you can execute whatever code you want just as long as the end result correctly returns true or false (or something that can be coerced to true/false).  So inside the Where scriptblock, I stash the fullname of the directory or file. Then I create a new pipeline where I send each element of the $exclude array down that pipeline.  That is wrapped in () to gather the output. Then we query to see if there's any output with count prop

Comment: Your first example works for me. However I was not able to use your or mjolinor's regex solution. See code on [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/809217eb899abd8fb35c)

Comment: What happened when you tried the regex?  I tested that, and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to build a regex from $folderExclude that that matches any of the exclusion strings (using alternation), then use -notmatch instead of -notlike.

```
$folderExclude = @(
    "C:\folder2", 
    "C:\folder1\folder3"    
    )

[regex]$Exclude_regex = ‘(?i)^(‘ + (($folderExclude |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)’

$fileInclude = @("*.txt", "*.hgr", "*.dat")           
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

gci $scriptPath -recurse -include $fileFilter | Where {$_.FullName -notmatch $Exclude_regex}
```

Edit: This might not be as "Posh" as the nested where-object, but it will be substantially faster.