# Omit multiple directories from get-childitem

Tags: regex, powershell, match, get-childitem

Found this thread: [Exclude multiple subfolders while using Powershell's method Get-Childitem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843753/1667496)
And managed to test it with the given parameters and it appears to function so I'm pretty sure the syntax I'm using is correct. However, obvsiously, it's not working for me given my parameters.

Stripped everything down to just two pertinant lines here:

```
$ExcludeDirs = @('$RECYCLE.BIN','Temporary ASP.NET Files','Temporary Internet Files','Temp','System Volume Information','RECYCLER')
gci -Path T:\ -Force -Recurse | Where {!($ExcludeDirs -match [regex]::escape($_.Fullname))}
```

Here's the first few lines from the output:

```
PS C:\Users\Angelo Mileto> $ExcludeDirs = @('$RECYCLE.BIN','Temporary ASP.NET Files','Temporary Internet Files','Temp','System Volume Information','RECYCLER')
gci -Path T:\ -Force -Recurse | Where {!($ExcludeDirs -match [regex]::escape($_.Fullname))}

Directory: T:\
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                      
d--hs        12/22/2013   4:57 PM            $RECYCLE.BIN                                                                                                              
d----        07/15/2012   2:19 PM            DropBox.Dir                                                                                                               
d----        12/09/2010   7:18 PM            ftproot                                                                                                                   
d----        07/27/2012   5:52 PM            GNS3                                                                                                                      
d----        08/16/2014   3:44 PM            New folder                                                                                                                
d----        05/10/2012   7:33 AM            ProgramData                                                                                                               
d--hs        04/13/2012   7:48 PM            RECYCLER                                                                                                                  
d----        03/10/2010   6:25 PM            SEP                                                                                                                       
d--hs        12/28/2012   5:42 PM            System Volume Information                                                                                                 
d----        08/08/2012   7:33 PM            Temp                                                                                                                      
d---s        03/12/2014   4:57 PM            Temporary Internet Files                                                                                                  
d----        09/24/2013   5:24 PM            VMWare_8.Dir                                                                                                              
d----        06/07/2008   7:06 AM            WINDOWS                                                                                                                   
-a---        08/18/2013  12:48 AM          0 Cleanup_T                                                                                                                 
-a---        12/15/2012   8:01 AM         68 Cleanup_T.txt                                                                                                             
-a---        03/14/2014   7:28 PM   24761548 Data_Hash1.txt                                                                                                            
-a---        03/14/2014   8:12 PM   24761548 Data_Hash2.txt                                                                                                            
-a---        09/24/2013   5:21 PM       3923 NewFolder.reg                                                                                                             
-a-hs        09/14/2014   2:02 AM 1717879193 pagefile.sys                                                                                                              
                                           6                                                                                                                           
-a---        09/24/2013   5:17 PM  335484316 Registry_BU.reg                                                                                                           
-a---        08/17/2014  11:58 AM       1020 TempHash.txt                                                                                                              
-a---        09/13/2014   6:29 PM      57466 VM_Hash1.txt                                                                                                              
-a---        08/17/2014  12:49 PM          0 VM_Hash2.txt                                                                                                              


Directory: T:\$RECYCLE.BIN
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                      
d--hs        04/28/2012   7:57 AM            S-1-5-18                                                                                                                  
d--hs        04/15/2012  12:01 PM            S-1-5-21-2447911456-218057785-4074464323-1000                                                                             
d--hs        05/07/2012   5:31 PM            S-1-5-21-3003357132-2481200545-788173088-1000                                                                             
d--hs        09/16/2014   7:31 PM            S-1-5-21-3108701050-3840048422-4210986610-1000                                                                            
d--hs        12/22/2013   4:57 PM            S-1-5-21-3108701050-3840048422-4210986610-1013                                                                            
d--hs        08/12/2012   7:00 AM            S-1-5-21-3201584925-4004853213-4110546137-1000                                                                            
d--hs        04/16/2012   8:10 PM            S-1-5-21-3464201764-390295408-3614804669-1000                                                                             
d--hs        12/15/2012   7:43 PM            S-1-5-21-3742232801-2663128855-664334430-1000                                                                             

    Directory: T:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-18
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                      
-a-hs        04/28/2012   7:57 AM        129 desktop.ini                                                                                                               

    Directory: T:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-2447911456-218057785-4074464323-1000
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                      
-a-hs        04/15/2012  12:01 PM        129 desktop.ini                                                                                                               

    Directory: T:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-3003357132-2481200545-788173088-1000
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                      
-a-hs        05/07/2012   5:31 PM        129 desktop.ini                                                                                                               

    Directory: T:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-3108701050-3840048422-4210986610-1000
```

Clearly you can see the first item in my ExcludeDirs variable is $RECYCLE.BIN - yes, realize it's not case sensitive for this function but like to keep it as precise as possible.

So the question is, why is it not working or what am I missing about using -match?

The overall goal is to end up with a list of all files on a given drive/directory tree that I can then act on but I want to omit stuff that changes all the time (i.e. the temp directories and such) while still getting listing of system and hidden files.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is in `$_.fullname` try to change it in `$_.name`

Comment: Walid, thanks for the input. Was working with $_.name for a it but then it would still process files inside of those directories unless you know another way to omit them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what I'd do. You have your array, and -match is really designed for strings not arrays, so let's convert your array to a regex match string. We'll run each item through `[RegEx]::Escape()` and join them with | and wrap it all in parenthesis:

```
$RegExExclude = "((?<=\\)$(($ExcludeDirs |ForEach{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join "(?=\\|$)|(?<=\\)")(?=\\|$))"
```

Now that comes out as the string:

```
(\$RECYCLE\.BIN|Temporary\ ASP\.NET\ Files|Temporary\ Internet\ Files|Temp|System\ Volume\ Information|RECYCLER)
```

Then we work that into your GCI like this:

```
$ExcludeDirs = @('$RECYCLE.BIN','Temporary ASP.NET Files','Temporary Internet Files','Temp','System Volume Information','RECYCLER')
$RegExExclude = "((?<=\\)$(($ExcludeDirs |ForEach{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join "(?=\\|$)|(?<=\\)")(?=\\|$))"
gci -Path T:\ -Force -Recurse | Where {!($_.FullName -match $RegExExclude)}
```

**Edit:** Updated per briantist's suggestion, it was an excellent one.

Comment: This is good, I would only point out that you can catch unintended things with this, for example if you had a directory called `C:\Program Files\App\Temporary\Whatever` it would be excluded (because `Temp` in the array would match it). You could change the regex building line as follows: `$RegExExclude = "((?<=\\)$(($ExcludeDirs |ForEach{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join "(?=\\|$)|(?<=\\)")(?=\\|$))"`. [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fAOKSrA3B93G6MCG)

Comment: Cool, upvoted, though my name is not Debuggex Demo ;-)

Comment: Wow, I feel sheepish. Sometimes I swear I'm better with computers than people. Fixed your name, credit where credit is due.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: you can use `-notmatch` operator instead of negate the `-match` operator ( operation in one step instead of 2) like this (untested):`..| Where {$_.FullName -notmatch $RegExExclude}`

Comment: @walidtoumi Yes, thank you, I'm aware, I was just trying to change their code as little as possible to make it functional.

Comment: Appreciate the imput from both Mad and Brian. I'm comfortable enough to building regular expressions that I could probably retype the array directly to the regular expression rather than having PS do the conversion for me.

I also did have it using -match at one point but it wasn't working and since the working version I had found was using -notmatch, just went with that. Will probably change back to -match if I get it working.

Will try it and report back.

Comment: If I type it out as a regular expression, should it be wrapped in " or '?

Comment: You probably need to put it in single quotes `'` otherwise you will end up with string interpolation in regards to $RECYCLE

Comment: Quick update. Got it working although still looking at the regex conversion. Not sure what the (?=\\) or (?<=\\) is doing. Thanks!!

Comment: Take a look at this [RegEx101.com breakdown](http://regex101.com/r/xR8pS7/1) and see if that doesn't answer your question for you.