# I would like to exclude the files in subfolders and delete files in the other folders

Tags: powershell

I have mulitple sub-folders in the main folder which has number of files in each of them. I want to keep the contents of certain folders intact and delete the contents in the rest of them.

I tested the code, but it deletes the files in all the sub-folders 7 days before.

```
$Path="C:\Shreyas1"
$NumberOfDays="-7"
$CurrentDate=Get-Date
$DeleteDays=$CurrentDate.AddDays($NumberOfDays)
## Heading
##$excludes="Specs"

Get-ChildItem $Path -Exclude $excludes -Recurse |
    Where-Object{($_.LastWriteTime -lt $DeleteDays )} |
    Remove-Item
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude multiple subfolders while using Powershell's method Get-Childitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842539/exclude-multiple-subfolders-while-using-powershells-method-get-childitem)

Comment: You should specify a little bit more. Are files you want to delete not in `C:\Shreyas` at all?  Also, does setting your `$currentDate` variable work when you set it as a `string` ($currentDate = "7") rather than an `int` ($currentDate = 7)?

Comment: `-Exclude` works only at the leaf level of a path. Also a [mcve] should include the desired behaviour and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Hey @Joseph, I have many sub-folders and each sub-folder has lot of files in them, apart from certain folders I want to delete the files in the other sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the same "Where" statement after your `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to filter out specific file names. Try something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*$excludes*" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DeleteDays}
```

Run that first to make sure you get what you want, then you can pipe to `Remove-item -Confirm:$false` like you have done in your OP. Edit: The `-Confirm:$false` switch means that it won't prompt you to confirm whether or not you want to delete the file, it will just delete. That is why you want to run `Get-ChildItem` first.